# How to display xAxis labels as timespans while allowing for > 24 hour durations in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I'm using the System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting chart object. I would like to add TimeSpan objects to the x-axis, but I don't know what the proper form is.

I'm adding points in a way like this:

```
 graph.Series[i2].Points[i3].XValue = DateTime.FromOADate(0).Add(temp).ToOADate();
```

where temp is the timespan of interest. I am still using datetime objects and converting them to doubles, because I don't know how TimeSpan objects would be represented in double form. Maybe this is my problem?

The Chart automatically generates these labels.

I currently have a line of code:

```
 graph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "T";
```

and this would display a timespan, but I need the timespan to represent days as well as hours. I need to the days to be 0 indexed, so it seems datetime objects are not an option (since March 0 doesn't exist).

Is there any way to do this?

I've been experimenting with lines such as

```
 graph.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTimeOffset;
```

but I have yet to find something that displays days and is not an actual date.

I'm not sure if the code would make the problem that much clearer, but if request I will post a requested excerpt. Please let me know if I can be more concise about a particular part of my problem.

Thanks guys

Comment: Check if the chart has an OnDraw event, where you can intercept the drawing of the label. If there is one, you can format it yourself, using Timespan.TotalDays, Timespan.Hours and TimeSpan.Minutes